# Removing the gap between two images in beamer

Tags: beamer, spacing, beamerposter

I am making multiple posters in beamer. The problem I am having is that on one of the posters (framed) there need to be 9 images (3 x 3) taking up the entire page. The images are inserted into one of 9 columns I have made. The problem is that there is a thin grey line between all of the images that I don't know how to get rid of:
[image]

This line is between all adjoining images. I have no idea how to get rid of it.

```
\begin{frame}

\begin{columns}
\begin{column}{0.333333\linewidth}
\includegraphics[width=1\columnwidth]{PNG's/1}
\end{column}

\begin{column}{0.333333\linewidth}
\includegraphics[width=1\columnwidth]{PNG's/2}
\end{column}

\begin{column}{0.333333\linewidth}
\includegraphics[width=1\columnwidth]{PNG's/3}
\end{column}
\end{columns}

\vspace{0cm}

\begin{columns}
\begin{column}{0.333333\linewidth}
\includegraphics[width=1\columnwidth]{PNG's/4}
\end{column}

\begin{column}{0.333333\linewidth}
\includegraphics[width=1\columnwidth]{PNG's/5}
\end{column}

\begin{column}{0.333333\linewidth}
\includegraphics[width=1\columnwidth]{PNG's/6}
\end{column}
\end{columns}

\vspace{0cm}

\begin{columns}
\begin{column}{0.333333\linewidth}
\includegraphics[width=1\columnwidth]{PNG's/7}
\end{column}

\begin{column}{0.333333\linewidth}
\includegraphics[width=1\columnwidth]{PNG's/8}
\end{column}

\begin{column}{0.333333\linewidth}
\includegraphics[width=1\columnwidth]{PNG's/9}
\end{column}
\end{columns}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Welcome! Please provide us with a complete minimal document we can compile to reproduce the problem. What does this have to do with LyX or the LaTeX 3 project? Are you using `beamerposter`?

Comment: Columns have space between them. You can set that to zero but that is not the best way to do this. Why do you want columns here anyway?

Comment: Just use `\includegraphics[width=.33\textwidth]{image1}\includegraphics[width=.33\textwidth]{image2}\includegraphics[width=.33\textwidth]{image3}` or whatever.

Comment: I don't really know of a better way, still very new to all of this. I figured that creating the columns like that would allow me to easily place the images. What approached would you suggest?

Comment: @P.OBOX Try to add the `totalwidth=\linewidth` option to your `columns` environments (the default `totalwidth` of `columns` is `\paperwidth`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple way is to stack every three images horizontally in a row, the width of each being `0.333333\linewidth`. Then, add a `\addvspace{-1pt}` command between any two rows to completely remove any extra vertical space in  a consistent way.

Note that `\addvspace` is preferable than `\vspace` in such situations where the vertical space is to be kept the same regardless of the preceding or the following environments.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{lmodern}    
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\includegraphics[width=0.333333\linewidth]{example-image-a}
\includegraphics[width=0.333333\linewidth]{example-image-b}
\includegraphics[width=0.333333\linewidth]{example-image-c}

\addvspace{-1pt}
\includegraphics[width=0.333333\linewidth]{example-image-a}
\includegraphics[width=0.333333\linewidth]{example-image-b}
\includegraphics[width=0.333333\linewidth]{example-image-c}

\addvspace{-1pt}
\includegraphics[width=0.333333\linewidth]{example-image-a}
\includegraphics[width=0.333333\linewidth]{example-image-b}
\includegraphics[width=0.333333\linewidth]{example-image-c}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I can not reproduce your problem. However, considering cfr comment, you can show pictures as follows:

```
\documentclass[xcolor={dvipsnames,table},11pt]{beamer}
\setbeamertemplate{bibliography item}[text]

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.32\textwidth]{example-image-a}
\hfil
\includegraphics[width=0.32\columnwidth]{example-image-b}
\hfil
\includegraphics[width=0.32\columnwidth]{example-image-c}

\smallskip
\includegraphics[width=0.32\textwidth]{example-image-a}
\hfil
\includegraphics[width=0.32\columnwidth]{example-image-b}
\hfil
\includegraphics[width=0.32\columnwidth]{example-image-c}

\smallskip
\includegraphics[width=0.32\textwidth]{example-image-a}
\hfil
\includegraphics[width=0.32\columnwidth]{example-image-b}
\hfil
\includegraphics[width=0.32\columnwidth]{example-image-c}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]